# Fallo al eliminar cookie en JS

Tags: javascript, cookies

Estoy probando este código:

```
console.log(document.cookie);
document.cookie = "test=hola; expires=Wed, 18 Dec 2026 12:00:00 GMT; path=/;";
console.log(document.cookie);
document.cookie = "test=; Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC; path=/;";
console.log(document.cookie);
```

Y obtengo este resultado por la consola:

```
test=nada
test=hola
test=nada
```

¿No debería eliminarse la cookie `test`? Estoy siguiendo las indicaciones de esta [otra pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/77369/eliminar-una-cookie-javascript) y las de [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp), pero no consigo que la cookie desaparezca. ¿Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: En esta línea tienes un error: `document.cookie = "test=; Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC; path=/;";` te falta `expires=` justo antes de la fecha.

Comment: ¡Eso era! Gracias @MauricioContreras

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eso es por que debes definir el path para asegurarte de que estas borrando la correcta.
En tu caso debería ser de este modo:

```
document.cookie = 'test=; Path=/; Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
```

En algunos casos, por lo que he encontrado, debes especificar el domain.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23995984/12429790

Test del caso

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Nada, continúa sin funcionar. Por si acaso, he probado a poner `Path` en mayúscula y colocarlo antes del `Expires`, pero nada...

Comment: Algo mal estás haciendo, por que estoy dejando hasta el ejemplo con tu codigo.

Comment: Eso seguro, porque a todo el mundo le funciona, menos a mí :) La cuestión es: ¿qué podrá ser?

Comment: El codigo que has dejado, es todo el codigo en cuestion ??

Comment: Sí, se ejecuta en el mismo bloque, no hay nada en medio. Eso sí, en el .php en el que está hay un montón más de código... pero no crea más cookies ni saca nada más por la consola

Comment: Te he dejado una imagen mostrando mejor el código.

Comment: Finalmente era un error de sintaxis. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: Era de suponerse, recuerda aceptar la respuesta para que quede completo el tema.